# Convert a list to comma separated strings for sql IN operator

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql

This seems very obvious use case and I am surprised I was not able to find any single working solution for this.

I have a method which returns a list of usernames something similar to this:

```
username = ["Tom", "Bob", "Charley"]
```

Now I want to use this variable to build a sql for IN operator, something similar to this:

```
sql = "Select * from users Where username IN %s" % username;
```

above line obviously fails due to syntax error.

Then I somwehere found that, I can change this to tupple:

```
username_tuple = tuple(username)
sql = "Select * from users Where username IN {}".format(username_tuple)
```

Above line works well but if there are just one string in the list (username = ["tom"]), then it fails with syntax error because username_tuple evaluates to ("tom",) (please note trailing comma after username.)

Comment: See here [List adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather then reinvent the wheel, use the built in list adaption from `psycopg2`. [List adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-list):

```
username = ["Tom", "Bob", "Charley"]
cur.execute("Select * from users Where username = ANY(%s)", [username])
```

Answer (score 3):

What you would like ultimately is a SQL string that can be used in a Prepared Statement where the `username` list can then be passed as arguments. That string would look like:

```
Select * from users Where username IN (%s,%s,%s)
```

and can be dynamically built with:

```py
username = ["Tom", "Bob", "Charley"]
params = ','.join(['%s'] * len(username))
sql = f"Select * from users Where username IN ({params})"
```

Then, you would get a `cursor` from your connection and execute the following:

```py
cursor.execute(sql, username)
```

**By using a Peepared Statement, you do not have to worry about escaping any special characters that might be in the user names nor do you have to be concerned with SQL Injection attacks.**

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at [SQL](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver `psycopg2` is suitable for PostgreSQL but the OP's question is also tagged for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
sql = "Select * from users Where username IN ({})".format(str(username)[1:-1])
```

Comment: That results in `Select * from users Where username IN (Tom,Bob,Charley)`. Does that look right to you?